# Keeping an alt branch up to date with common

Tags: git, rebase

I've got a repository that has two branches: `common` and `alt`. The `common` branch holds the version of the code that is the most common use case for most people. The `alt` branch holds a version of the project where some things are configured differently but most things are the same as on `common`.

Up until now, I've been happily developing on my machine by applying bug fixes and development to the `common` branch and then rebasing those changes onto `alt`. `alt` has some commits that I do not pull back into `common`. These changes are totally perpendicular to the changes on `common` since `alt` just adds and removes some files.

To give an example here's how the code might look right after I changed some stuff in `common` but didn't rebase them onto `alt` yet.

```
A -- B -- C -- F   (common)
     \
      `-- D -- E   (alt)
```

and after the rebasing:

```
A -- B -- C -- F              (common)
     \
      `-- C --- F -- D -- E   (alt)
```

However, I've recently put up the project on github, posting both branches on there.  It seems I cannot use rebase anymore to keep `alt` up to date with `common` since every time I do:

- edit something in `common` and commit
- checkout `alt` and `git rebase common`
- `git push github alt`

This says that the local branch of `alt` is running behind on the remote one, now I always need to pull and merge first. This creates a lot of clutter merge commits that I feel shouldn't be necessary (their diffs are empty).

How can I better manage my branches so that changes in `common` can be pulled into `alt` and so that I can keep both `common` and `alt` on github too?

Comment: Maintaining multiple long-lived branches is painful (as you're discovering).  You should strongly prefer a single branch, and using configuration options to distinguish between the two variants.

Comment: this technique is called [feature toggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle)

Comment: Yes but as it is a boilerplate project, I think that doesn't really apply. Splitting the repo is also a no-go since much code is shared.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look on [gitflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DpUH.png)
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

This workflow is designed to answer workflow like yours where you need to commit few changes to several branches.

#### How?

The gitflow is simply a set of scripts which you can configure as you wish according to your needs.

The default scripts (workflow) is described in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Gitflow isn't designed for arbitrary workflows, it's designed for the Gitflow branching model.

Comment: Agree, but i don't see any other way beside modifying the scripts. The other options is to manage it manually which will not be a better choice. So i would got on gitflow with custom modifications